# Bash - Delete lines ending with a number

Tags: linux, bash

I need to remove only lines (in text file) ending with a number.

Before:

```
1987 Robocop
1990 Robocop 2 
1993 Robocop 3 
2014 Robocop
```

After:

```
1987 Robocop
2014 Robocop
```

Comment: Show us the attempts you've made any tell us how they failed to work.

Comment: Take a look at "regular expressions" and a tool to apply them, like `grep` or `sed`.

Comment: `([0-9]+ Robocop [0-9]+)\g`

Comment: it tried this but it doesn't seem to change anything. --  sed '/[0-9^]$/d' file

Comment: @Seaner992 test with http://www.regexr.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're referencing my [favorite movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093870), I'll answer:

```
sed '/[ \t][0-9][0-9]*[ \t]*$/d' movies.txt
```

Which translates to:

> Delete any line where there is either a space or a tab, followed by at least one digit, then any amount of spaces or tabs at the end of a line.

There are more compact ways to represent this on Linux, but I gave you one that does it the hard way for portability's sake.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
sed '/[0-9]$/d' file
```

If you want to edit "in place" add option `-i`.